# Is visibility inverted between objects and modifiers?

Tags: rigging, drivers, visibility

I copy and pasted a driver from a modifier's visibility buttons to an objects visibility buttons, but the resulting visibility is opposite for the object. As in, a driver value of 1 for the modifier results in visibility being true, and for the curve object the same driver value of 1 results in visibility being false. Is this intentional behavior, or is there something I am missing? It doesn't seem to be documented but maybe I missed it. The driver is working, moving the bone to get a driver value of 0 toggles both.

[image: Modifier Driver]
[image: Object Driver]

Comment: "Component" here is a little vague-- looks like you mean a modifier, but there are a lot of potential things you could mean, and each could be something different.  The driver properties for object visibility don't agree with object visibility text, however.  Outputting "true" to object visibility hides objects.  I always figured this was more of an interface issue, where the text/checkmark is backwards, too smart for its own good.

Comment: Fixed it, I meant modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the underlying variable is inverted. For modifiers its `.show_viewport` and for objects its `.hide_viewport`. Weird.

[image: .show_viewport]
[image: .hide_viewport]